# Template actual data context

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have troubles with data context;

Here is my code (unfortunatly, meteorpad is broken)

**router.js(I use iron:router)**

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'    
});

Router.route('home',{
    path: '/',
    action: function(){
        this.redirect('sections', {page: 0});
    }
});

Router.route('sections', {
    path: '/sections/:page',
    data: function(){
    var data = {};

    data.params = {};
    data.params.page = this.params.page?this.params.page:0;

    return data;
 }
});
```

**template.html**

```
<template name="layout">
    {{>yield}}
</template>

<template name="sections">
    Page: {{params.page}}
    <br>
    <a href="{{pathFor 'sections' page=0}}">Page 0</a>
    <a href="{{pathFor 'sections' page=1}}">Page 1</a>
    <a href="{{pathFor 'sections' page=2}}">Page 2</a>
    <br>
    <button>what page?</button>
</template>
```

**template.js**

```
Template.sections.onRendered(function(){
    let scope = this;

    $("button").on("click", function(){
        alert("page: " + scope.data.params.page);
    });
});
```

When I click button, button-handler has the scope, which had the template, when rendered, but not actual in this moment;

Comment: Does `Blaze.getData(scope.view)` instead of `scope.data` work? BTW you'd be better off with a `Template.sections.events({...})` instead of using jQuery.

Comment: yep! Blaze.getData(scope.view) works! Thank you!
I use Template.sections.events({}), if it possible.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @user3374348

method Blaze.getData(scope.view) returns actual data context.

**template.js**

```
Template.sections.onRendered(function(){
    let scope = this;

    $("button").on("click", function(){
        alert("page: " + Blaze.getData(scope.view).params.page);
    });
});
```